# Add jquery function to an Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h90Luy3h/), in it I have a table that has a clickable row  that expands and shows information related to that record, in this case the parent row is a category and the child shows information related to a subcategory. My issue is that if I add a second category row the last row is the one that expands, what I need is that any parent row expands because the number of subcategory records for each parent row could bring different number of subcategories.

```
$scope.category = [
   {
     "desc": "CATEGORY 1",
     "LW$": "45",
     "LW": "-4%",
     "L4W": "-15.7%",
     "L13W": "24%",
     "L52W": "-6%"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and logical) to nest the data:

```
$scope.category = [
    {
        desc: "CATEGORY 1",
        "LW$": "45",
        "LW": "-4%",
        "L4W": "-15.7%",
        "L13W": "24%",
        "L52W": "-6%",
        subcat: [
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 1",
                "LW$": "45",
                "LW": "-4%",
                "L4W": "-15.7%",
                "L13W": "24%",
                "L52W": "-9%"
            },
            {
                "desc": "SUB CATEGORY 2",
                "LW$": "15",
                "LW": "4.2%",
                "L4W": "1.7%",
                "L13W": "-2.4%",
                "L52W": "-65%"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then, nest the two ng-repeat something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="d in category">
    <tr class="parent">
        <td ng-class="expand" drill-down>+</td>
        <td>{{d.desc}}</td>
        <td>{{d.LW$}}</td>
        <td>{{d.LW}}</td>
        <td>{{d.L4W}}</td>
        <td>{{d.L13W}}</td>
        <td>{{d.L52W}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="s in d.subcat" class="child">
        <td ng-class="expand" drill-down>+</td>
        <td>{{s.desc}}</td>
        <td>{{s.LW$}}</td>
        <td>{{s.LW}}</td>
        <td>{{s.L4W}}</td>
        <td>{{s.L13W}}</td>
        <td>{{s.L52W}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This will work, but I advise you to replace the jQuery function with an Angular function (something like [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), or just show and hide with ngShow)

Please find a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7dtfz486/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just one more thing, what if I want to add a third level below subcat, like item, I try this  <tr ng-repeat="f in d.subcat" class="grandson"> but aint work :(

Comment: In that case you're iterating through subcategories of the subcategory and then the `ng-repeat` should be `f in s.subcat`. And make sure it's within the parent `ng-repeat`. This might require some changes to your HTML.